# how to typecast Html5File to java.io.File in vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

```
public void drop(DragAndDropEvent dropEvent) {

        WrapperTransferable tr = (WrapperTransferable) dropEvent.getTransferable();
        Html5File[] files = tr.getFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (final Html5File html5File : files) {
                final String fileName = html5File.getFileName();

                final ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                StreamVariable streamVariable = new StreamVariable() {

                        public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
                            return bas;
                        }
                        public boolean listenProgress() {
                            return false;
                        }
                        public void onProgress(StreamingProgressEvent event) {
                        }
                        public void streamingStarted(
                                StreamingStartEvent event) {
                        }
                        public void streamingFinished(
                                StreamingEndEvent event) {
                            progress.setVisible(false);
                            showFile(fileName, html5File.getType(), bas);
                        }
                        public void streamingFailed(
                                StreamingErrorEvent event) {
                            progress.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        public boolean isInterrupted() {
                            return false;
                        }
                    };
                    html5File.setStreamVariable(streamVariable);
                    progress.setVisible(true);


                    encryptAndUploadFile( ***html5File****, fileName, folderName);
```

// How can I convert this html5File to java.io.File because I have one encryptAndUploadFile method which accepts file Parameter

```
                }
            }
     }
```

// encryptAndUploadFile() Method

```
  public void encryptAndUploadFile(File file, String fileName,String folderName) 
  {
    String  m_strWebFilePath = finalSourcepath + fileName;
    File m_objFile=null;
    byte[] sourceFileByte = Encryption.aesEncrypt(com.saterisystems.common.utils.FileUtils.getImageIntoByteArray(file), GlobalConstants.KEY.getBytes(), GlobalConstants.IV.getBytes());
    ......
    ......
    ......
```

Please suggest me how can I typecast this Html5File type object to java.io.File type object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: 
I've read again the documentation and demo code they have. It seems when drag and dropping files with Vaadin the actual upload is handled by it. The real problem is you want to encrypt them before it goes to the server (from the method you want to call).

I think I've figured out a way to upload it encrypted. Look at this code from the demo here http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/other/drop-items:

```
if (files != null) {
    for (final Html5File html5File : files) {
        final String fileName = html5File.getFileName();

        if (html5File.getFileSize() > FILE_SIZE_LIMIT) {
            Notification
                .show("File rejected. Max 2Mb files are accepted by Sampler",
                                          Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        } else {

            final ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final StreamVariable streamVariable = new StreamVariable() {

                 @Override
                 public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
                      return bas;
                 }

                 @Override
                 public boolean listenProgress() {
                      return false;
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onProgress(
                      final StreamingProgressEvent event) {
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void streamingStarted(
                      final StreamingStartEvent event) {
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void streamingFinished(
                      final StreamingEndEvent event) {
                      progress.setVisible(false);
                      showFile(fileName, html5File.getType(), bas);
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void streamingFailed(
                      final StreamingErrorEvent event) {
                      progress.setVisible(false);
                 }

                 @Override
                 public boolean isInterrupted() {
                      return false;
                 }
             };
             html5File.setStreamVariable(streamVariable);
             progress.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

} else {
     final String text = tr.getText();
     if (text != null) {
         showText(text);
     }
}
```

It seems it requires you to provide an OutputStream for the data to be sent to the server. You could subclass the ByteArrayOutputStream class and override the write(byte[] b) method to encrypt the data before it gets to the superclass write method like this:

```
public class EncryptedArrayOutputStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream {

@Override
public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException{
    byte[] encrypted = encrypt(b);
    super.write(encrypted);

}

private byte[] encrypt(byte[] bytes) {

    byte[] encrypted = new byte[bytes.length]; // This also might not be the size depending on the algorithm you choose
    // Your algorithm here....
    return encrypted;
}
}
```

Comment: html5File.getFileName() gives only fileName not whole file path. so while  this statment **File file = new File(html5File.getFileName())** throws Exception.

Comment: Html5File supports only (Name,FileSize,Type)